# kafkaProducer parameter not in JSON format

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, xml-parsing, apache-camel, spring-kafka

I am getting below error after upgread the java verison from 1.8 to 11

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: kafkaProducer parameter not in JSON format:$propertySource.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.producer.configuration
at org.kp.wpp.abp.kafka.DbOptKafkaRecordProcessor.determineKafkaProducer(DbOptKafkaRecordProcessor.java:95) ~[asyncBatchProcessor-1.0.39.jar:?]
at org.kp.wpp.abp.kafka.DbOptKafkaRecordProcessor.initialize(DbOptKafkaRecordProcessor.java:59) ~[asyncBatchProcessor-1.0.39.jar:?]
at org.kp.wpp.abp.batch.RecordProcessorConfigFactory.createRecordProcessor(RecordProcessorConfigFactory.java:130) ~[asyncBatchProcessor-1.0.39.jar:?]
at org.kp.wpp.abp.batch.RecordProcessorConfigFactory.create(RecordProcessorConfigFactory.java:71) ~[asyncBatchProcessor-1.0.39.jar:?]
at org.kp.wpp.abp.batch.RecordProcessorConfigFactory.retrieve(RecordProcessorConfigFactory.java:63) ~[asyncBatchProcessor-1.0.39.jar:?]
at org.kp.wpp.abp.batch.RecordProcessorConfigFactory.find(RecordProcessorConfigFactory.java:47) ~[asyncBatchProcessor-1.0.39.jar:?]
at org.kp.wpp.abp.batch.RecordManager.configure(RecordManager.java:148) ~[asyncBatchProcessor-1.0.39.jar:?]
at org.kp.wpp.abp.batch.RecordManager.initialize(RecordManager.java:135) ~[asyncBatchProcessor-1.0.39.jar:?]
at org.kp.svctxn.batch.SvcTxnInsertManager.initialize(SvcTxnInsertManager.java:24) ~[svcTxnLoggingUtil-1.0.65.jar:?]
at org.kp.dss.is.config.SvcTxnDefaultConfig.init(SvcTxnDefaultConfig.java:42) ~[classes/:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2683.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) [spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) [spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) [spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) [spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:920) [spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) [spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) [spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) [spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175) [spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155) [spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97) [spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174) [spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebApp.java:2581) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.79.jar:?]
at [internal classes]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initi
alize(WebApp.java:6705) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.79.jar:?]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:474) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.79.jar:?]
at [internal classes]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]

I want to get the Kafka producer from Azure Cloud config server but that data is coming in yaml file and application is expecting in JSON format. I am getting mentioned error. Can someone help if any changes are required or dependencies to be updated.
Technologies:
Java11
Kafka
Camel
Springboot
Azure cloud environment